# Landscape Adding Administrator in a Closed Network Environment

Tags: ssh, landscape

Just testing out Landscape in a closed network environment (we are looking for a solution that can managed updates for a few hundred devices, but all of these device are hosted in a closed network environment [ie: no internet]).

So while we are considering using landscape to managed that, one issue that I can not resolve in a closed network, is that I can not any additional administrator in a closed network (the only way on the GUI to add administrator is to enter someone email and landscape will send that person an email setup link, but obviously it is not gong to work on a closed network).

And unfortunately, I will not be able to provide a proxy network that can patch in a connection to email server or anything like that, this is a 100% closed network environment.

Is there any way to add additional administrator on landscape via SSH or command line something inside a 100% closed network environment? Any advise will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One way that I can think about it is to grab a unique link from the actual e-mail sent via postfix. You would have to set up [always_bcc](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#auto_bcc) to a user/email that you already have on the box. Once this is done, send the invite and check via mutt or other CLI mail client for the BCC'ed email.

Another thing to think about it is - how do you want to manage updates? Landscape is checking at least every hour for security updates, and others. Not allowing Landscape to connect to outside will limit its capabilities. You will also miss on email alerts that packages are available etc.

But let's approach that one problem at a time :)